# What is happening to the state when I save it to a variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm testing a little bit with the spotify API and came across this and I found it very strange.

Basicly I'm setting the variable `testarr` equal to the state. Then I wanted to update only the `testarr` variable. But when I run this function and log to the console both the state `songList` and `testarr`, they are the same. What I find strange is that I don't ever update the state so how can it be changed?

[image: Image of the console log]

```
testing(){
    let testarr = this.state.songList;
    let testsongs = this.state.songs;

    for(var i = 0; i < testsongs.length; i++){
      for(var j = 0; j < testarr.length; j++){
        if(testsongs[i] === testarr[j].songname){
          testarr[j].count += 1;
          testarr.push({
            songname: 'hej',
            count: 1
          });
        }
      }
    }

    clearInterval(this.interval);
    console.log("songlist ");
    console.log(this.state.songList);
    console.log("songs " + this.state.songs);
    console.log("tessong " + testsongs);
    console.log("testarr ");
    console.log(testarr);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set your variable like that:

```
let testarr = this.state.songList;
```

actually you are not creating a different array at all. Your new `testarr` variable actually points the original array here. Hence, when you change the new array, original one changes too.

```js
const foo = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
const bar = foo;
bar[0] = 100;
console.log( foo );
```

You should not mutate the state like that. You can create a new array with [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) like that:

```
let testarr = [ ...this.state.songList ];
```

Or you can prefer `concat` which also does not mutates the original array:

```
let testarr = this.state.songList.concat( [] );
```

With this way, when you change the new `testarr` original one is kept as it is.

```js
const foo = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
const bar = [ ...foo ];
bar[0] = 100;
console.log( foo );
```

So, never mutate your state when coding with React. Always make a copy either with the spread syntax or the `concat` method. Use `slice` instead of `splice` when you changing your arrays because the latter also mutates the original array.

This concept also applies to objects. Do not mutate them.